# Xamarin Custom Renderer. Place view on the bottom of the screen

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, renderer

I want to use BottomNavigationView in Droid project (from Xamarin.Android.Support v25) and wrote a custom renderer. All is good but i cannot place it on the bottom of the screen :)  I need to implement onLayout and onMeasure functions but when i write them like this:

```
    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        var c = _bottomBar.MeasuredHeight;

        _bottomBar.Layout(0, 0, _bottomBar.MeasuredWidth, _bottomBar.MeasuredHeight+b-t);
        var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(_currentPage);
        renderer.UpdateLayout();

    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        SetMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(heightMeasureSpec, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        _bottomBar.Measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);


    }
```

i get bottom part of the menu outside the screen. How to rewrite this?

P.S. Please do not suggest to use any libraries, I need to use native lib.

Comment: In your _bottomBar.Layout call, what's the point of _bottomBar.MeasuredHeight+b-t for the last argument. Why are you adding and subtracting there? And why are you laying it out to the top left corner (0, 0) if you want it on the bottom?

Comment: "a custom renderer"? Which base renderer are you using to create your custom renderer? Are you actually using Xamarin forms for Android project or are you using Xamarin.Android?